When loading data into a BigQuery table using Polars, how can I load data into a field with List[Struct] schema?
My target table has a schema like so:

I have a polars data frame like this:
import polars as pl

example_data = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "numbers": [
                {"value": "abc", "name": "one", "id": "1"},
                {"value": "def", "name": "two", "id": "2"},
                {"value": "ghi", "name": "three", "id": "3"},
            ]
        },
        {
            "numbers": [
                {"value": "jkl", "name": "four", "id": "4"},
                {"value": "mno", "name": "five", "id": "5"},
            ]
        },
        {"numbers": []},
    ]
)

Which therefore has a schema like this:
OrderedDict([('numbers',
              List(Struct({'value': String, 'name': String, 'id': String})))])

However if I try and load that into a new bigquery table like so:
import io

from google.cloud import bigquery

project_id = "REDACTED"
location = "REDACTED"
dataset_id = "testing"

client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id, location=location)

client.create_dataset(f"{project_id}.{dataset_id}", exists_ok=True)

table_id = f"{project_id}.{dataset_id}.example_wrong_schema"
client.create_table(table_id, exists_ok=True)

table = client.get_table(table_id)
with io.BytesIO() as stream:
    example_data.write_parquet(stream)
    stream.seek(0)
    job = client.load_table_from_file(
        stream,
        destination=table,
        project=project_id,
        job_config=bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
            source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.PARQUET,
            write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
        ),
    )
job.result()

The resulting bigquery schema is:

And if I try to write my polars dataset to the target table, I get an error:
400 Provided Schema does not match Table REDACTED. Cannot add fields (field: numbers.list); reason: invalid, message: Provided Schema does not match Table REDACTED. Cannot add fields (field: numbers.list)

How can I wrangle my poalrs dataframe, or even the underlying arrow/parquet, so that it will write to this schema?

I solved this, but not in a very nice way. You can use newline-delimited-json to load the data:
from orjson import dumps

json_bytes = b""
for idx, row in enumerate(example_data.to_dicts()):
    if idx == 0:
        json_bytes += dumps(row)
    else:
        json_bytes += b"\n" + dumps(row)

json_data = json_bytes.decode()
buffer = io.StringIO(json_data)

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
job_config.autodetect = True
job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE

load_job = client.load_table_from_file(buffer, table_id, job_config=job_config)
load_job.result()

